# Some HTML tags disappear when i use PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to generate dynamic contents fill from mysql db
here is my php code:

```
<?php 
    include 'header.php'; 
    error_reporting(1);
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $dbName = "haimi";
    mysql_connect('localhost', $user, $pass) or
        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbName);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Projects ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>

<?php
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
        <li class="filter" data-filter=".cat<?php echo $line['Category'];?>"><?php echo $line['Category'];?></li>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

The `li` displays correctly, but the following does not:

```
<div class="row projects m0">
<?php
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        <div class="project mix catHouses">
            <div class="tint"></div>
            <a href="images/projects/".<?php echo $line['ProjectImage1']; ?> data-    
lightbox="project" data-title="Central Hospital (building)">
            <img src="images/projects/".<?php echo 
$line['ProjectImage1']; ?> alt="<?php echo $line['ProjectTitle'];?>"   
class="projectImg"> </a>
            <div class="projectDetails row m0">
                <div class="fleft nameType">
                    <div class="row m0 projectName"><?php echo $line['ProjectTitle'];?></div>
                    <div class="row m0 projectType"><?php echo $line['ProjectType'];?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="fright projectIcons btn-group" role="group">
                    <a href="images/projects/<?php echo $line['ProjectImage1']; ?>" data-lightbox="project" data-title="Central Hospital   (building)" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-    search"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
</div>
```

It data in the `div`s doesn't appear.

Comment: is the $line array populated?

Comment: @user2547783 Is that a no?

Comment: please print a sample data of the database result line variable

Comment: Yes it's 
it's populate data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a single call, but trying to loop through it twice.  To do so, you need to reset the pointer back to the beginning:

```
//Add this after the first loop, but before the second
mysql_data_seek( $result, 0 );
```

The way you have it now, it's `while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result))`, but the second loop is never entered since it has already reached the end.  Since the loop is ended, it never displays the contents.

**Important Note**
The mysql_* functions are deprecated, and is removed in PHP 5.5.  You should use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  They have better protections against mysql injections (see [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)).

Comment: Thank U Mr Matthew @Matthew Johnson

Answer (score 1):

You have some HTML mistakes here:

```
<a href="images/projects/".<?php echo $line['ProjectImage1']; ?>
```

First, there is no need to use `.` operator (as you are in HTML, not PHP),
Also you shoud put your `<?php ?>` tag inside the `href` quotations, here is the correct code:

```
<a
    href="images/projects/<?php echo $line['ProjectImage1']; ?>"
    data-lightbox="project"
    data-title="Central Hospital (building)"
>
    <img
        src="images/projects/<?php echo $line['ProjectImage1']; ?>"
        alt="<?php echo $line['ProjectTitle']; ?>"   
        class="projectImg"
    >
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get older fast writing code like that ;)
How about this:

```
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $category = $line['Category'];
    echo <<< LOB
<li class="filter" data-filter="$category">$category</li>
LOB;
}
```

Comment: i want to populate divs with specific content

Comment: But you do have a problem in a way you write your code, it's very confusing and it may lead to errors, like the one you've now. My answer was about that.

Comment: i did ur way (best one) :)
but i have the same result
thank u for ur advice about my code. I am beginner :(

Answer (score 0):

Like what Mr @matthew said

I was making a single call, and I was trying to loop through it twice.

The problem solved with this code before the while loop:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```